# Getting error while using jackson annotation @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, mapping

Hello guys I am getting error as follows while making request from post man

`org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Could not resolve type id '4' as a subtype of` com.myproject.onetoone.viewmodels.request.TopicGenerationRequest`: known type ids = [GoalsGenerationRequest, TodoGenerationRequest, TopicGenerationRequest]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id '4' as a subtype of` com.myproject.onetoone.viewmodels.request.TopicGenerationRequest`: known type ids = [GoalsGenerationRequest, TodoGenerationRequest, TopicGenerationRequest] at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 2, column: 13]`

my parent class:

```html
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = GoalsGenerationRequest.class, name="GoalsGenerationRequest"),
    @Type(value = TodoGenerationRequest.class, name="TodoGenerationRequest")
})
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TopicGenerationRequest {
      private int type;
}
```

Child class GoalsGenerationRequest:

```html
import com.myproject.onetoone.viewmodels.request.TopicGenerationRequest;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@JsonTypeName("GoalsGenerationRequest")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GoalsGenerationRequest extends TopicGenerationRequest {
    private List<Goal> goals;
}
```

Child class TodoGenerationRequest:

```html
@JsonTypeName("TodoGenerationRequest")
@Getter
@Setter
public class TodoGenerationRequest extends TopicGenerationRequest {

    @NotNull(message = "A valid UUID must be passed")
    private UUID ownerId;

    @NotBlank(message = "valid title should be added")
    private String title;

    private ZonedDateTime deadline;



}
```

Child class of GoalsGenerationRequest named Goal:

```html
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Goal {
    private int type;
    private int id;
}
```

Request made from postman as follows:

```html
{
    "type": 4,
    "goals": [
        {
            "type": 3,
            "id": 456
        },
        {
            "type": 3,
            "id": 454
        }
        ]
}
```

The end point where request is mapped has following logic:

```html
 Mono<ProfileIdentity> profileIdentityMono = Utility.getUserPrincipal().map(UserPrincipal::getProfileID);
        Mono<TopicGenerationRequest>  generationRequest = serverRequest.bodyToMono(TopicGenerationRequest.class)
            .onErrorResume(castError -> Mono
                .error(new ClientErrorException(ErrorCodes.INVALID_REQUEST, "please provide valid json body")));
```

Kindly help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you define two known subtypes:`GoalsGenerationRequest` and `TodoGenerationRequest` so you should used in your JSON payload, but you set to `4` which is not matched any known subtype, so you should set to any of known types. For example:

```
{
    "type": "GoalsGenerationRequest",
    "goals": [
        {
            "type": 3,
            "id": 456
        },
        {
            "type": 3,
            "id": 454
        }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, it worked. I have to add type field explicitly that decides the class with which data has to be mapped
{
    "type": "GoalsGenerationRequest",
    "sectionType": 3,
    "goals": [
        {
            "type": 3,
            "id": 467
        }
        ]
}

Comment: @Deepak007 Nice, if this answer worked, please mark it as answered and upvote if you want.